# Problems with WiFi after recent loading of Loki 0.4

Tags: wifi

After recently installing Elementary Loki 0.4 I cannot seem to get WiFi to work and updates are stalled "waiting for package manager lock" after authentication. this seems to mean that I cannot load/update anything that might allow me to configure the wifi network connections. Is this a problem with my basic install? I see screenshots showing a configuration tool after "installing upgrades" , but cannot seem to get this to work!

Answer (score 1):

Try manualy updating elementary os. Open a terminal with Super + T, then...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If it says anything about package locks, follow the steps that it provides. You may have to preform some action, such as running a specific command. Otherwise you can continue by typing

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Dont worry, this will not upgrade your os to ubuntu 16.10 ;)